# How to use Dense Rank and automatically generate dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two questions in regards to DENSE_RANK and the other based on inserting dates. Basically I have 2 leagues with 4 teams per league. Each league has a round of fixtures like so:

```
    League 1

    Week1: 1v4, 2v3  - Date: 10-June-2016
    Week2: 1v3, 2v4  - Date: 17-June-2016
    Week3: 1v2, 3v4  - Date: 24-June-2016

    League 2

    Week1: 5v8, 6v7 - Date: 10-June-2016
    Week2: 5v7, 6v8 - Date: 17-June-2016
    Week3: 5v6, 7v8 - Date: 24-June-2016

(They play each other home and away)
```

- Ok so league 1 and League 2 is (LeagueID 1 and League ID 2)
- Week 1 and 2 are displayed under WeekNumber column
- Teams 1 -8 have their own IDs (TeamID which is then displayed as HomeTeamID and AwayTeamID)
- Date goes into a column which is FixtureDate

My questions are:

1- How under WeekNumber can I set it so that the group of games mentioned, it notices them as these games belong to week 1, these week 2, these games week 3 etc.

2- How to auto generate the date so that if week 1 is played 10 June 2016, the next round of fixtures are played 7 days later, then the round after 7 days later etc.

Below is what the table looks like currently:

```
WeekNumber  HomeTeamID   AwayTeamID  FixtureWeek  LeagueID
1           1             4          NULL         1
1           1             3          NULL         1
1           1             2          NULL         1
1           2             3          NULL         1
1           2             4          NULL         1
1           3             4          NULL         1
1           5             8          NULL         2
1           5             7          NULL         2
1           5             6          NULL         2
1           6             7          NULL         2
1           6             8          NULL         2
1           7             8          NULL         2
```

Below is what it should like:

```
WeekNumber  HomeTeamID   AwayTeamID  FixtureWeek  LeagueID
1           1             4          10-06-2016         1
2           1             3          17-06-2016         1
3           1             2          24-06-2016         1
1           2             3          10-06-2016         1
2           2             4          17-06-2016         1
3           3             4          24-06-2016         1
1           5             8          10-06-2016         2
2           5             7          17-06-2016         2
3           5             6          24-06-2016         2
1           6             7          10-06-2016         2
2           6             8          17-06-2016         2
3           7             8          24-06-2016         2
```

Below is my current code which needs to be modified but I need help with this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Fixture_Insert]
 @LeagueID INT


AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN

INSERT INTO dbo.Fixture (WeekNumber, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, FixtureWeek, LeagueID)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.LeagueID) AS WeekNumber,
    h.TeamID,
    a.TeamID,
    NULL AS FixtureWeek, -- Don't know what to set this to for automatic dates
    h.LeagueID
FROM dbo.Team h
CROSS JOIN dbo.Team a
WHERE h.TeamID <> a.TeamID
AND h.LeagueID = a.LeagueID

END
```

UPDATE:

I've applied images to showcase what is happening so you can see what needs to be done to fix it (the table displayed is when I did a select* from dbo.Fixture):

[image]

The proc I excuted for the above is displayed here:

[image]

Comment: Will be nice to provide DDL and DML statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @StartFixtureWeek date = '2016-06-10'

;WITH team AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,2),(6,2),(7,2),(8,2)
) as t (teamid, leagueid)
)
, cte AS (
SELECT  h.teamid AS HomeTeamID,
        a.teamid AS AwayTeamID,
        h.leagueid AS LeagueID
FROM team h
CROSS JOIN team a
WHERE h.teamid != a.teamid AND h.leagueid = a.leagueid
), final AS (
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.LeagueID  ORDER BY c.LeagueID, c.HomeTeamID, c.AwayTeamID) as rn,
        c.HomeTeamID,
        c.AwayTeamID,
        c.LeagueID
FROM cte c 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 a.HomeTeamID, a.AwayTeamID 
    FROM cte a 
    WHERE a.LeagueID= c.LeagueID and a.AwayTeamID=c.HomeTeamID and a.HomeTeamID =c.AwayTeamID
    ORDER BY a.HomeTeamID, a.LeagueID) as b
WHERE c.HomeTeamID < b.HomeTeamID
)

SELECT  CASE WHEN rn > 3 THEN rn-3 ELSE rn END as WeekNumber,
        HomeTeamID,
        AwayTeamID,
        CAST(DATEADD(week,(CASE WHEN rn > 3 THEN rn-3 ELSE rn END)-1,@StartFixtureWeek) as date) FixtureWeek,
        LeagueID
FROM final
```

Output:

```
WeekNumber           HomeTeamID  AwayTeamID  FixtureWeek LeagueID
-------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1                    1           2           2016-06-10  1
2                    1           3           2016-06-17  1
3                    1           4           2016-06-24  1
1                    2           3           2016-06-10  1
2                    2           4           2016-06-17  1
3                    3           4           2016-06-24  1
1                    5           6           2016-06-10  2
2                    5           7           2016-06-17  2
3                    5           8           2016-06-24  2
1                    6           7           2016-06-10  2
2                    6           8           2016-06-17  2
3                    7           8           2016-06-24  2

(12 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: I'm actually looking at your solution now, it's just the row number where I hope it's correct. I'll let you know in five minutes what it outputs. Thank you for the answer

Comment: The dates worked fine (I did remove the SELECT before you posted your answer). The problem is the week number, like I said you have the teams play their round of matches one week and then their next round of matches are played another week. What's happening here is every match has their own week number as if one match is played a week

Comment: Dense_rank, I should have tried that earlier. You almost got it. It starts the rank again back to 1 it's a new home team. So if team 1 vs 4 is week 1, it will do team 4 vs 1 as week 1 as well. We need that one to have a different rank as it's home and away, does that make sense?

Comment: It's my bad because in the example I set the output as what I though but completely forgot about what happens for away fixtures as well

Comment: Man, what you want to achieve? :) I am beginning to loose the clue. I add partition by hometeamid to get numeric diapasons for each team starting by 1.

Comment: What needs to be acheived is the number of rounds played in a league. Each team plays against each other home and away. So if there are 4 teams, the should be 6 rounds (or weeks whatever you want to call it) of matches. So it should display for week numbers 1 through 6. With the way we have it partitioned, it will display 1 - 3 again if we reverse the fixtures, rather than 4 - 6

Comment: Try changing PARTITION BY LeagueId in my answer.

Comment: That wouldn't in my example as it will make leagueID ambiguous. As i'm doing a cross join for 'Team' table to 'Team' table to set my home and away teams, it will ask which team table to take the league ID. If I select one of leagueID column (e,g h.LeagueID), it will rank each match as its own week and only start from 1 again if a new league

Comment: I rewrite the question totally. Get a look, please.

Comment: Hey! Have you check it? Just curious :)

Comment: Hi buddy, sorry for lateness. I've tested it and it worked fine, thank you very much for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter to your stored procedure called `@StartFixtureWeek DATETIME`

Then you can use `DATEADD`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Fixture_Insert]
 @LeagueID INT,
 @StartFixtureWeek DATETIME


AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN

INSERT INTO dbo.Fixture (WeekNumber, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, FixtureWeek, LeagueID)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.LeagueID) AS WeekNumber,
    h.TeamID,
    a.TeamID,
    SELECT DATEADD(day,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.LeagueID)-1)*7,@StartFixtureWeek) AS FixtureWeek, 
    h.LeagueID
FROM dbo.Team h
CROSS JOIN dbo.Team a
WHERE h.TeamID <> a.TeamID
AND h.LeagueID = a.LeagueID

END
```

Comment: It's still doing the same thing. In my EXEC PROC do I need to set a date because I set it to 06-10-2016 and it applies that date to all game. The WeekNumber is still displaying a number per row like last time. I've attached a screenshot that shows what is happening.